# use pic10f222 internal absolute voltage refrence

Tags: microcontroller, pic

I want to use PIC10f222 ADC and have no prolem in it :

```
#include <10F222.h> 
#list 
#device PIC10F222 
#device adc=8 
#FUSES NOWDT                    //No Watch Dog Timer 
#FUSES NOPROTECT                //Code not protected from reading 
#FUSES NOMCPU                   //Master Clear Pull-up disabled 
#FUSES NOMCLR 
#FUSES IOSC4                    //INTOSC speed 4 MHz 
#device adc=8 
#use delay(internal=4000000) 
#define set_options(value){#ASM    \ 
                 MOVLW value   \ 
                   OPTION        \ 
                 #ENDASM} 

setup_adc(true); 
set_tris_b (0b111); //set as output 
set_options(0xDF);  // Enable pin B2 for normal i/o 
set_adc_channel(0); 
adc1=read_adc();
```

But, when when VDD changes the ADC shows different values (and that is also OK because the reference voltage is VDD).
I looked in PIC10F222 data sheet and found "absolute voltage refrence" that equals :
result = 0.6 * 256 / VDD 
I thougth I can get VDD from the equation above and then get the precise adc value as follow:

```
adc_set_channel(2); 
adc1=read_adc(); 
vdd=0.6 * 256   / adc1  ; 
adc_set_channel(0); 
adc=read_adc(); 
//get the percise adc in popotion of VDD 
....
```

But the adc1 (absolute voltage reference is not going to chane with different VDD from 4.9 to 5.2),
How can I fix this problem?

Comment: > But the adc1 (absolute voltage refrence is not going to chane with different VDD from 4.9 to 5.2),
How can i fix this prroblem?

Comment: > But the adc1 (absolute voltage refrence is not going to chane with different VDD from 4.9 to 5.2),
How can i fix this prroblem?

Are you observing adc1 not changing while changing VDD? Or are you stating this? The latter is incorrect.

In C, 'vdd=0.6 * 256   / adc1' will always result in zero, perhaps, that's why you see the behaviour you're describing.

Comment: Your question, as asked, cannot be answered. Over the 4.9 to 5.2 VDD voltage range the ADC result will change about 1 or 2 counts. I do not see a solution in firmware for the PIC10F222.

Comment: Why are you working with float values?

Answer (score 0):

To read the absolute voltage reference on the 10F2xx PIC families, which is 0.6V, then do this in the CCS C Compiler (which looks like what you are using):

```
set_adc_channel(2);
```

If you are using a different compiler, then do this:

```
ADCON0 = (ADCON0 & 0xF3) | 0xC;
```

This does not completely answer your question, as you are implying that you want to set the PIC's ADC to use this absolute voltage reference for ADC conversions of the other channels.  This PIC does not support this.  But you could use the ADC reading of this absolute voltage reference to determine what your VDD actually is, and then make necessary compensation of the ADC reading in software.